# Issue regarding fetching some records from table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a User model. Now I have an array named id_array containing certain ids such as:

```
id_array=[123,145,229]
```

Now is there any rails way to get only those records from users table with these matching ids in id_array by using active record query?

I don't want to write a do-each loop to achieve this. I just want a single active record query which will give the result.

Please help me if there is a way. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an array for a column translates to `WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3)` in sql. 
`all` triggers the query and returns the results.

```
User.where(id: id_array).all
```

Comment: @7urkm3n Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, you can simply pass ruby `Array` to your `ActiveRecord` query, like this:

```
User.where(id: id_array)
```